# ember-simple-auth user stays logged in despite browser relaunch

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

For some reason my user is still logged in despite closing my Safari browser.

These are the versions of Ember & stuff that I'm using:

```
ember-cli: 3.25.3
node: 14.16.0
os: darwin x64
```

This is my authentication code:

```
this.session.authenticate('authenticator:devise', this.fields.email, this.fields.password)
```

And this is my `app/services/session.js` file:

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import BaseSessionService from 'ember-simple-auth/services/session';

export default class SessionService extends BaseSessionService {
  @service currentUser;

  async handleAuthentication(routeAfterAuthentication) {
    try {
      await this.currentUser.load();
      super.handleAuthentication(...arguments);
    } catch(err) {
      await this.invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm checking my logged in status via:

```
this.session.isAuthenticated
```

It says here https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/CookieStore.html that:

> By default the cookie session store uses a session cookie that expires and is deleted when the browser is closed.

So how come my user is still authenticated despite closing my browser - any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The cookie store isn't the default store. You'll need to configure this like:

```js
// app/session-stores/application.js
import Cookie from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/cookie';

export default class ApplicationSessionStore extends Cookie {}
```

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/3.1.0-beta.0#session-stores) in the README.